# Delete numerals at the end but keep dates and text

Tags: regex

I'm a beta tester for a hockey game and sometimes the schedules I get are fouled up. Can anyone help this Notepad-challenged newbie?

Turn this:

```
19;10;2012;Oklahoma City Barons;San Antonio Rampage323
19;10;2012;Milwaukee Admirals;Charlotte Checkers572
19;10;2012;Manchester Monarchs;Providence Bruins002
19;10;2012;Albany Devils;Syracuse Crunch579
```

Into this:

```
19;10;2012;Oklahoma City Barons;San Antonio Rampage
19;10;2012;Milwaukee Admirals;Charlotte Checkers
19;10;2012;Manchester Monarchs;Providence Bruins
19;10;2012;Albany Devils;Syracuse Crunch
```

Thanks!

Comment: regex '\d+$' or '[0-9]+$' (some regex engines like one and not the other) will match digits at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To teach you some regex...**

1. First you can match digits with `\d`
2. Secondly, you can "anchor" the match, the `$` means "the end of the string"
3. Finally, you want to specify 1 or more digits, so you add the `+` quantifier to the `\d` token I mentioned earlier to create `\d+`

   3.1. If the numbers are not ALWAYS on the end, make it optional with `*` ('0 or more') `\d*`

---

Full regex: `\d+$` or `\d*$`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Perl`:

```
cat file | perl -ne 's/\d+$//' > newfile
```

Where file is the file with the numbers and newfile is the corrected entry.

Comment: Thank you all for your knowledge. It worked. Is there a site I can learn regex? I hate to keep asking for help. Unfortunately, I only have a 2 week turnaround on these schedules I do for Franchise Hockey Manager made by OOTP, so that's why I asked here. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: This is probably as good of an introduction to regexes as any; the regex are not as powerful as Perl's, but it's a good start: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html#Regexp